# ArangoDB - How to get relations between 2 collections

Tags: arangodb, aql, foxx

I have 2 vertex collections:

- `users`
- `articles`

and 1 edge collection:

- `userfollow` (relation between user following other users)

The problem is when user follow other users and the followed users wrote some articles, how to get the articles based on the user following?

Comment: How do you store the relation between a user and the article he/she wrote? Is there an array of document handles (article IDs), or is there another edge collection to store these relations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query the data with AQL's native graph traversal in Foxx using [db._query()](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/Manual/Foxx/GettingStarted.html#writing-database-queries).

### Sample data

users:

```
{ "_key": "john-s", "gender": "m", "name": "John Smith" }

{ "_key": "jane.doe", "gender": "f", "name": "Jane Doe",
  "article_ids": [
    "salad-every-day",
    "great-aql-queries"
  ]
}
```

articles:

```
{
  "_key": "great-aql-queries",
  "title": "How to write great AQL queries"
},
{
  "_key": "salad-every-day",
  "title": "Delicious salads for every day"
}
```

userfollow:

```
{ "_from": "users/john-s", "_to": "users/jane.doe" }
```

### Query

Starting at follower *John*, we can use [AQL traversal](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/AQL/Graphs/index.html) to get all users he is following. Here, there is only Jane being followed:

```
FOR v IN OUTBOUND "users/john-s" userfollow
    RETURN v
```

The document keys of the articles Jane wrote are stored in the Jane user document itself, as an array of strings (you could also model this with edges of course). We can use [DOCUMENT()](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/AQL/Functions/Miscellaneous.html#document) to fetch the articles and return them:

```
FOR v IN OUTBOUND "users/john-s" userfollow
    RETURN DOCUMENT("articles", v.article_ids)
```

We could also return who John is following (Jane), remove the `article_ids` attribute for each user and merge in the full article documents:

```
FOR v IN OUTBOUND "users/john-s" userfollow
    RETURN MERGE(UNSET(v, "article_ids"), {
        articles: DOCUMENT("articles", v.article_ids)
    })
```

The result looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "users/jane.doe",
    "_key": "jane.doe",
    "gender": "f",
    "name": "Jane Doe",
    "articles": [
      {
        "_key": "salad-every-day",
        "_id": "articles/salad-every-day",
        "title": "Delicious salads for every day"
      },
      {
        "_key": "great-aql-queries",
        "_id": "articles/great-aql-queries",
        "title": "How to write great AQL queries"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```